# How to use the IIS server in a VM on Mac host?

Tags: macos, iis, vmware, localhost

I need to access my http://localhost/ (in IIS 6 on VM) from the MAC Host (Safari).

I am using NAT (or can use Bridged) network connection to the Guest, but not sure how to identify IP addresses, etc.  A novice when it comes to networking ;-)

Thanks,
Geoff

Comment: Hi. i think you need write not localhost from your real machine but ip address of virtual machine. If i understand your question

Answer (score 4):

A simple solution if you want a consistent hostname is to install [Bonjour for Windows](http://support.apple.com/kb/dl999) in the VM with bridged networking and then use http://*computername*.local in Safari.

It's possible to forward ports from a NATed VM too or ensure a consistent IP address if you want; some instructions are [here](http://nileshk.com/2009/06/24/vmware-fusion-nat-dhcp-and-port-forwarding.html).

Answer (score 1):

In Safari, you should be able to type in the IP address of your VM and be able to access IIS that way. Firewall settings permitting of course, but I assume you've set that up already.

If it doesn't work, could you please post more details about your current setup (VM software being used to run the guest, OS X version, Windows version) and I'm sure we'll be able to troubleshoot further.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I find the IP address of the VM if in a Bridged connection? I'm using latest OSX on Host, and WinXP Pro on VM.

Comment: If you really want to do it that way, you can use ipconfig in Windows each time, or if you follow the link I mentioned in my answer, you can also configure a static lease that VMware Fusion's DHCP server can assign.  But I think simply using mDNS with Bonjour is the simplest solution.  (Any changes you make to VMware Fusion's NAT configuration will get blown away on Fusion updates, too.)

Answer (score 1):

Just try to off Windows firewall on your virtual machine. This works for me in NAT mode.

Also, as mantioned before, is nice to have [Bonjour for Windows](http://support.apple.com/kb/dl999) installed to have more useful URL.